# get all elements with onclick in them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am looking for a way to list all elements that have `onclick` event on a page.

Comment: Firequery maps everything bound to html elements, I don't know how it works, but if no one know you can try to check the source... https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12632/ http://firequery.binaryage.com/shared/img/firequery-mainshot-full.png

Answer (score 5):

Edited to answer further questions...

---

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but I suspect you're looking for a way to see if there has been code attached to an element's onclick event? If so, try this:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for ( var i = 0; i<allElements.length; i++ ) {
    if ( allElements[i].className !== 'theClassNameYoureLookingFor' ) {
        continue;
    }
    if ( typeof allElements[i].onclick === 'function' ) {
        // do something with the element here
        console.log( allElements[i] );
    }
}
```

If you'd like some information about the actual function attached to the onclick event, you'll need to make use of Firebug or something similar to output the function and examine it as it will have been possibly generated at runtime (ie the function declaration might not just be sitting on the page where it could theoretically be accessed easily). Try using the code provided above, but instead of

> console.log( allElements[i] );

do

> console.log( allElements[i].onclick );

Now, in firebug, you can mouse over the functions it prints and see their code.

Comment: well i have a page with a bunch of divs that share the same class name. those divs also have onckicks attached to them. I want to extract the data that is inside each onclick. I believe the code posted above would list all teh elements on page... so, i need to get all elements with the same class name, and then get the parameters that are in each onclick

Comment: Post edited to provide more information. Be sure to read bobince's answer as well as he makes some good observations.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from @Josh the Goods didn't work for me, I had to slightly modify it.

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    if ($._data(allElements[i])['events'] != undefined 
        && $._data(allElements[i])['events']['click'] != undefined) {
        console.log(allElements[i]);
        for (var ii = 0; ii < $._data(allElements[i])['events']['click'].length; ii++) {
            console.log($._data(allElements[i])['events']['click'][ii].handler);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery >= 1.4, you can get an Array of all elements with onclick attribute by writing the oneliner:

```
$('body *').toArray().filter(function(el) { return $(el).attr('onclick') });
```

Answer (score 1):

> i need to get ... the parameters that are in each onclick

You can read the string value of the `onclick` attribute by using:

```
var onclickstr= allElements[i].getAttributeNode('onclick').value;
```

inside Josh's code (this is a slightly roundabout method, required for IE).

Of course it would only work for event handlers attached from inline event handler attributes, not assigned to the `onclick` property from JavaScript or added via `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`.

Trying to prise values out of a JavaScript code string is an ugly and unreliable hack that you shouldn't resort to unless there's really no other option. If the page is something you're generating yourself, you should instead use unobtrusive-scripting techniques. Omit inline event handler attributes like `onclick` completely (today they're considered bad practice) and attach handlers from JavaScript itself, using parameters stored in easier-to-access places like classname and other ‘spare’ attributes where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Get an array of all elements with an onclick attribute

```
   Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[onclick]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy if the traditional/old school method of event handler attachment is used (the following code is untested).

```
var getEventHandlers = function(nodes, eventType) {
    var handlers = [], h;

    for ( var i=0, l=nodes.length; i<l; i++ ) {
        h = nodes[i].getAttribute(eventType);
        if ( typeof h === "function" ) {
            handlers.push(h);
        }
    }

    return handlers;
};
```

Use:

```
console.log(getEventHandlers($("*"), "onclick"));
console.log(getEventHandlers($(".some-class"), "onclick"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For a succinct jquery selector, you could use `$('[onclick]')` however that would only get elements wit the onclick **attribute** set.