# How to select elements with event attributes using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, events

Hope there's a simple workaround for this.
I want to select all the html elements with event attributes. For example: onclick, onkeypress etc. Is there an easiest way to do this using Jquery without selecting by each attribute seperately?

Thanks

Comment: Surprisingly, non of the answers given so far answered your interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the short answer to your question is *no*.

Different HTML tags support different events, so they should be hardcoded somewhere in the jQuery code. And reading through the jQuery code, I cannot find any reference to onkeypress event, for example.

So, I think you can just rely on [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) `[attribute]`:

```
$('[onclick], [onkeypress], [etc]');
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value is not specific, you can try [this approach](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

The demo below prints *"hey you people"*, based on `$([attr1],[attr2],...,[attrN])` selector:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>no id</div>
    <div id="a">hey</div>
    <span name="b">you</span>
    <p id="c">guys</p>
</div>​

$('[id],[name]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});​
```

Based on that construction, simple wrapper can be written:

```
$.fn.hasAttrib = function() {   
    var attributes = [];
    $.each(arguments, function(index, value){
        attributes.push('[' + value + ']');
    });
    return $(this).find(attributes.join());
};
```

Usage of such plugin in the statement below also prints *"hey you people"*:

```
$('.container').hasAttrib('id','name').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: gdoron is right. He wants to know if there is a kind of :hasEvent selector, instead of listing all the events.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom filter function to find elements with an attribute that starts with **on** , like so:

```
$.fn.filterOn = function() {
   this.each(function(ind,el) {
       var attrs = el.attributes;
       for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
           if (attrs[i].nodeName.indexOf('on') === 0) return true;       
       }
       return false;
   });
};
```

and use it like:

```
//elems will contain all input fields with an attribute starting with 'on'
elems = $(':input').filterOn();
```

And this will give you ALL elements in the page that has an attribute starting with **on** (beware of performance when using ***** selector):

```
$("*").filterOn().each(function() {
   console.log('Element '+this.tagName + ' has an on... attribute');
});
```

Comment: This is safe only if you work only with standard HTML attributes.

Comment: @LucaFagioli Yes, I'm just trying to add another possibility to tackle  the OP's problem, I understood for his case the events are connected via standard html attributes. The OP knows his html template better and he will know if my solution can be useful for his specific case or not, I'm just adding different solutions to the plate :-)

Comment: And it is a weak check. Although it is has a correct syntax (in the context of only standard HTML attributes), different HTML tags support only a subset of such events. You should also add a check against the map [tag::[attributes]]. But I believe it starts to be too cpu consuming.

Comment: Personally I find your solution not a bad solution, I was just trying to make a constructive criticism :)

Comment: and thanks for that, constructive criticism is always welcome :-)

Comment: @Nelson Thank you for this solution.. In my case I can't guarantee that the html on which this script run has only standard attributes. Anyways nice try.. thanks for the effort.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse all elements and check. Not really efficient, but it should works.

Check [get all elements with onclick in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878445/get-all-elements-with-onclick-in-them)

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for ( var i = 0; i<allElements.length; i++ ) {
    if ( allElements[i].className !== 'theClassNameYoureLookingFor' ) {
        continue;
    }
    if ( typeof allElements[i].onclick === 'function' ) {
        // do something with the element here
        console.log( allElements[i] );
    }
}
```